# Validation for a ListBox is not working while submitting form in asp.net mvc

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4

I created ListBoxFor in my view and want to put a Required attribute , Already checked the other threads on stack overflow on this .

All the other dataAnnotation is working while submitting & method IsValid in custom List is hitting after submission sending false but in that mean time the form is already submitted and gone to other page

As if while submitting its just ignoring this CustomList Annnotation

**custom list attribute**

```
[AttributeUsage(AttributeTargets.Property)]
    public sealed class CustomListAttribute : RequiredAttribute
    {
        public override bool IsValid(object value)
        {
            List<SelectListItem> list = value as List<SelectListItem>;

            return (list != null && list.Count > 0);
        }


    }
```

**model**

```
[CustomList(ErrorMessage="Atleast select one value")]
[DisplayName("tea Values")]
public List<SelectListItem> TeaValues { get; set; }
```

**View**

```
 @Html.ListBoxFor(m => m.TeaValues , new List<SelectListItem>(), new { id = "TeaValuesId" })
@Html.ValidationMessageFor(m => m.TeaValues )
```

Comment: You cannot bind a `<select>` to a collection of complex objects (which is what `List<SelectListItem>` is). A `<select multiple>` posts back an array of simple values. The property you bind to needs to be `IEnumerable<string>` (or `IEnumerable<int>` etc

Comment: made it IEnumerable<string> and in view @Html.ListBoxFor(m => m.TeaValues , Enumerable.Empty<SelectListItem>(), new { id = "TeaValuesId" })   --- still its not working

Comment: There are multiple other problems with your code (and `Enumerable.Empty<SelectListItem>(),` makes no sense - your not even generating any options). And you should not be inheriting fro `RequiredAttribute`, but if you do then you must register it in `global.asax`.

Comment: I suggest you read [The Complete Guide To Validation In ASP.NET MVC 3 - Part 2](https://www.devtrends.co.uk/blog/the-complete-guide-to-validation-in-asp.net-mvc-3-part-2)